# Why use route parameters when the primary key is contained in the DTO?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Webapi code often has methods like this in the controller:

```
[HttpPut]
MyPutMethod(int id, SomeDTO dto){
   //update record with record.id == id
   //etc.
}
```

I have dtos which have a member called 'id' so I'm wondering what the point is of specifying the primary key of the object in the URL path rather than the parameter 'id'.

Could someone please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of having the ID as a parameter is that it allows every `Some` to be treated as a resource with a persistent URL (part of being the service being RESTful).

As to why `SomeDTO` has the ID as well, I suspect it's because it might be used for other purposes. For example, if you had a GET method that returns multiple `SomeDTO`, you'd probably want the ID to be within each `SomeDTO`. The alternative approach is to have DTOs that are specific to each request and response (and therefore the DTO for the PUT request wouldn't have an ID). I'd say there are pros and cons to each approach to modelling DTOs. Having a single DTO is simpler in some ways, but then doesn't clearly explain the semantics of each request/response, and may complicate validation. On the other hand, multiple DTOs has clearer intent, but then requires more development, and perhaps makes changes harder to propagate.